# Does django have a built-in way of limiting the number of objects a one-to-many relationship can have?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm working on a project in django and I have the following (abbreviated) user class:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  max_files = models.IntegerField(default=5)
```

And then I have another class,

```
class File(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Does django have any way to do either of the following:

1. Limit the number of `File`s that my `CustomUser` class has (limit the number of the "many" in the one to many  Foreign Key field) to a constant number
2. The above, but instead of a constant number the use the `User.max_files` entry

I don't currently have any database constraints, but I'm planning on using MySQL, so if this is database-specific assume I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `save()` method of your model to check if you have exceeded the max number. Overriding model methods is documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Alternatively If you are using a `ModelForm` you can implement validation as documented on the Django doc pages:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/